# Define composition of small cyles and making a big graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation, definition

> I am having following sub graphs and wish to compose all and make a
>   one bigger graph (say G). After that, I want to select the closed path
>   where it is passing along the outer vertices of that bigger graph (say
>   outerloop). I think I can get this *outerloop* by getting *union* of each
>   sub graph and then getting *difference* of *intersection* of adjacent sub
>   graphs from that union.

If I show this Pictorially, it looks like below. 
[image]

Once I did this, the final outerloop would be like; {1,2,6,7,9,8,10,11,10,7,6,5,3,4,3,1}

> When I describe this in a formal mathematical way with notations, It is
>   as follows. I am sure, this explanation does not say exactly what I
>   did.

[image]

**

> So, Could you please correct this explanation with mathematical
>   notations. thank you in advance.

**

Comment: This is not a BINARY operation!

Comment: @Boris Novikov: sorry. I am not an expert and used wrong terminology. So I will update the post.